# Name of BigQuery SQL Syntax

Tags: google-bigquery, grammar

Do we have a name for syntax that is being used for BigQuery SQL? It's like BNF/EBNF but I'm not sure.

```
UPDATE target_name [alias]
SET update_item [, update_item]*
[FROM from_clause]
WHERE condition

update_item ::= path_expression = expression
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a type of extended BNF, but it does not seem to have a clear formal description.

Some of the constructs seem to me to be appeals to the reader's intuitions rather than formal description, and some of the formal structure is conveyed by the text's font.

As is common in this sort of documentation, some aspects of the syntax are described in the narrative, so that the formal syntax is actually a superset of the accepted language.

None of that is intended as a criticism. (Although in principle, it would be nice if grammars were described using a formalism both easy to read for humans and amenable to machine analysis.)